# How to do Multiple words with Autocomplete Textbox WP Toolkit?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, autocomplete, windows-phone-toolkit

I am using the windows phone toolkit but am wondering if this is possible.

Say I have the word "Kraft Dinner"

If the user starts to type "Kr..." autocomplete will kick in but if they type "Din..." it won't because it seems like it need first the word "Kraft".

Is there a way so it would see "Dinner" as part of that autocomplete?

I have in my code behind constructor

```
  AutoCompletions = new List<string>()
        {
            "Kraft Dinner"
        };
  acbAddItem.ItemsSource = AutoCompletions;
  public IEnumerable AutoCompletions { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's quite simple, all you have to do, is to set `FilterMode` property.
For example:

```
   <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox  FilterMode="Contains"  Height="74" InputScope="Url">
   </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

**see also**

[AutoCompleteBox.FilterMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.filtermode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)